# Chrome extension development: permissions, activeTab, I'm confused

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, manifest.json

I have developed a simple chrome extension which generates QR codes through a form which triggers an API. Through JavaScript the qr code is displayed to the user, and through a button is possibile to download the qr code image.
Since this is a simple extension which is not going to "listen" to or interacting with any users' activities, and since it's not going to change the content of the pages the user visits, what kind of *browser_action* and *permissions* I have to set into the manifest.json file?
I'm a bit confused by permissions, activeTab, <all_urls>.
I've read some documentation, but I didn't find any match to what my extension will perform: it feels like I don't have to set any permissions, is that possible? Please help!
Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: It's perfectly fine to not request any permissions. The question is unanswerable without code though...

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, finally I've discovered that I didn't need any content_scripts matches, thank you anyway!